# Accessing Android SD Card

Tags: mount, android, sd-card

New here so please bear with me!

I have an SD Card with some photos on it. It is formatted for an old Vodafone Android phone but the phone does not work any more so I need to access the card directly.

I cannot see how to mount an Android formatted SD Card directly in Linux such that I can see the photo files on the SD Card.

Would anyone be able to give me a step by step process to access the photos. I am relatively inexperienced with Linux but used to programme in Unix so am picking things up quickly.

I am running Ubuntu. I have an SD card slot that works fine with other SD cards.

Disks shows the SD card with:

- Partition 1 (17MB): Device `/dev/mmcblkop1`
- Partition Type `19a710a2-b3ca-11e4-b026-10604b889dcf`
- Contents Unknown
- Partition 2 (8.0GB): Device `/dev/mmcblkop2`
- Partition Type `193d1ea4-b3ca-11e4-b075-10604b889dcf`
- Contents Unknown

I ran `sudo fdisk -l` which shows:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7969 MB, 7969177600 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 965 cylinders, total 15564800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Device            Boot      Start     End       Blocks    Id    System
/dev/mmcblk0p1  

        1         15564799  7782399+  ee    GPT
```

I also ran `sgdisk --print /dev/mmcblk0`:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15564800 sectors, 7.4 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 6117AB28-D818-4C73-A33A-5F6E0A26B696
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 15564766
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048           34815   16.0 MiB    FFFF  android_meta
   2           34816        15564766   7.4 GiB     FFFF  android_expand
```

Further details from `sudo lsblk -f /dev/mmcblk0`:

```
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL           MOUNTPOINT                             
mmcblk0                            
├─mmcblk0p1                        
└─mmcblk0p2
```

`sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="46C204CAC204BFE3" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="EA66089566086523" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Data" UUID="06B6D646B6D635C1" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="cd798835-cf23-496a-a826-8603c60a3ecb" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="de9c0c43-0775-421c-9b9c-4063fdf6a236" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb: LABEL="Mark SSD1" UUID="F44401DF4401A588" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="040D813E3C84050B" TYPE="ntfs"
```

I think that the android phone must have encrypted the card, hence why nothing is visible and as a result it will be impossible to retrieve any of the photos. If anyone believes there is a way to recover them then please let me know.

**QUESTION: how to mount a GPT system?**

Comment: The computer your using should have a slot for the type of SD card your trying to mount else it won't be able to mount it. And note linux does this automatically just put it in the right slot on your pc and it will pop up.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu? Have you got a card reader? Did you try to read the card simply by connecting and trying with Ubuntu's file browser? If it does not work 'out of the box', you can try to identify the partitions and mount them manually with command lines in a terminal window. Please describe with more details 'what you have and where you are now'!

Comment: you can use back-ticks for code formatting (`) but you're off better to include your findings by doing an [edit] to your question.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f` with the SD card plugged in?

Comment: @DavidFoerster - I've added the output of lsblk to the original question.

Comment: It looks like the Linux kernel sees the SD card. So far I can't tell what Linux thinks is on there though. The output of `sudo lsblk -f` is implausible. Are you sure that's what it shows? It should be more akin to [this example](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1663825#p1663825). Could you please try again? If that doesn't work could you please try `sudo blkid /dev/mmcblk?p*` please? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - I've added the output to the original question. sudo blkid /dev/mmcblk0 did not output anything so I included the output of sudo blkid instead to show what was visible. P.S. other SD Cards work fine in the slot.

Comment: The SD card contains a working partition table and Linux can read the partitions but doesn't recognize what's on them. It may be encrypted or simply garbage. I don't know how Android organises its storage.

Comment: ok - thanks, that confirms what I expected, that it cannot be read because it is encrypted. An unfortunate mistake in the process of upgrading to a new bigger SD card, every day is a school day.

Comment: Here is some useful information for recovery android_expand data:
https://nelenkov.blogspot.ru/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html There said, that data at SD-card is encrypted and to read it you ought to have a key, which is stored at device memory. As your device does not work, it seems you can't read your photos.

Answer (score 4):

You’ve surely already found this informative blog post: [Decrypting Android M adopted storage](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, the meta partition contains the encryption key, which is itself encrypted by your phone unlock, and that key is used to encrypt the expand partition. Once decrypted (requires the phone that owns the partition to be rooted), you get a plain EXT4 partition that you can do whatever with.

Answer (score -2):

This post is quite old, so it probably does not help you anymore. Anyway, the filesystem used by your SD card is probably extended FAT, which, I think, is not supported by default.
Installing support for this filesystem should be sufficient:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse
```

Comment: No, it's not exfat.. the partition layout (`android_meta`, `android_expand`) clearly shows this card has been formatted using the "[Adoptable Storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable)" mode.